# What Selenium and Firefox version is best to use?

Tags: selenium, firefox, version

Which Selenium and Firefox versions shall I use to start learning Selenium. None of my code from Packt Publishing book "Selenium... a practical guide" is working. 
The book says they Selenium Java 2.33.0 and Firefox 17.
Has anyone had any success running the book's code on any latest version of Selenium and Firefox? Please suggest.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: selenium server stand alone last version and chromedriver last version, is working better with chrome than with firefox. For selenium 3.0 you need to specify the driver first java -jar -Dwebdriver... selenium-server-stanalone..

Answer (score 0):

Use selenium 2.53 and firefox 46. Firefox >= 47 use [marionette driver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver), but is in development and some things dont work, like Actions.